# How do I match two arrays with duplicates in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know this removes duplicates :

```
@email.distributions.map(&:zip_code) & CardSignup.all.map(&:zip_code)
```

But I want to do the same thing, where I find anything that matches, but it also shows me duplicates.

Any ideas?

I am trying to find the amount of people who signed up for a card that have a matching zip code to a zip code preference I placed.

Comment: What is the (approximate) size of these two arrays? Is one much bigger than the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Array#reject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000258) to the rescue, again! Like [`Array#map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000247), it accepts blocks, allowing you to do something like this:

```
zip_codes = CardSignup.all.map(&:zip_code)
@email.distributions.reject{|o| !zip_codes.include?(o.zip_code)}
```

Oh, but of course, if you like finding more elegant ways, always consider the operators like you already did. `&` will return a new array with objects that are in both, `|` will join and remove duplicates.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > [1,2] | [2,3]
 => [1, 2, 3] 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > [1,2] & [2,3]
 => [2]
```

Edit: as Tokland said in the comments, since this is applied on a Rails Model, you may want to consider doing it as a select. Like this -

```
zip_codes = CardSignup.all.map(&:zip_code)
@email.distributions.where('zip_code IN (?)', zip_codes)
```

Or, do it with an INNER JOIN. Doesn't look as pretty though.

```
@email.distributions.joins('INNER JOIN card_signups ON card_signups.zip_code = email_distributions.zip_code').all
```

(If the table for @email.distributions is email_distributions..)

Comment: Ahh what lucid clarity I have now. Thank you so much fx_

Comment: If you sea a negated reject you may write it as a select. Also, it may be worth considing using a set for "zip_codes" so the include? is O(1)